# HTML5 Date picker opens up only on 2nd click

Tags: android, html, mobile, datepicker, tablet

I am using HTML5 date picker for my date calendar date box(`input type="date"`). However in Nexus 7 Chrome 36 and Motorolla Chrome 33, I found out that , we need to click on the date box twice for the date picker to open up . What is the reason behind it ? How can this problem be solved ?

Comment: Guys any help will be deeply appreciated ! I am at my wit's end here . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with http://jsfiddle.net/y3ozjjbt/ ? Do you use any additional attributes on the `input` element? Do you have any JS events attached to this element?

Comment: @lxg : This cannot be reproduced properly in a desktop browser. You need to open the jsfiddle in the chrome browser version of the mobile devices that I had mentioned. Only then it can be replicated.There are no js events for the input presently. Point to be noted here is that : when i open this in my LAVA Qpad : Chrome 33, it works properly on single tap. On Samsung, Motorolla and Droid chrome versions , it works only on double tap if the field is empty. If the field has date value, then it works on single tap.

Comment: As a workaround, can you just always give the field an initial (perhaps null) value?

Comment: @scottt : Lemme try that . Will let you know after i try that .

Comment: @scottt : No , this cannot be done. We cannot set null value .

Comment: I am using nexus,, its works fine for me

Comment: Cannot repro with Chrome 36 (on kitkat 4.4.4)

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue as well - Chrome 37.0.2062.117 / Android 4.4.4. Are you sure you don't have any event listener bound to the input or perhaps the `<body>`, which may be the cause?

Comment: Thanks Guys . It seems to be a HTML5 compatibility issue with browser versions. In case, I come across any definite answer I will post it here .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the HTML5 datepicker is only partially supported. Maybe this problem will go away as support improves?

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Answer (score 0):

The only possible explanation given such less input is that when you open up your webpage, it's zoomed out. By default when you touch any input element when the page is zoomed out, android will zoom in the region and you'll be required to touch again just to confirm what you touched.

To get rid of it, you can simply zoom in before touching or just build a mobile specific website using jQuery mobile or something...

Answer (score 0):

The default HTML5 date-picker might be conflicting with another library you are using. As per [html5test](http://html5test.com/s/b7c6b1221d1fed32.html) your browser is supported for the default date. I hope you are testing with an actual device. Could you try with a simple page with only `< input type="date" />`

Comment: Yes, I have tested with actual device . The problem persists there, but in other chrome versions like 34,35 and recently play store release 37, I am not able to find any problems except in those other chrome versions for those specific devices.